# Подписаться на событие внутри job

Tags: c#, планировщик-задач, quartz

Используется Quartz.NET. Есть класс

```
class SampleJob : IJob
{
   public delegate void SampleNotification(string message);
   public event SampleNotification OnEvent;  

   public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
   {
       OnEvent(messageString);
   }
}
```

создаю планировщик:

```
var job = JobBuilder.Create<SampleJob>().WithIdentity(jobName, groupName).Build();
var trigger =
    (ICronTrigger)
        TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(triggerName, groupName)
            .WithCronSchedule(cronLine)
            .Build();
//добавляю job и trigger в Scheduler
```

Возможно ли подписаться на event внутри `Execute` `SampleJob` из того места где он добавляется в планировщик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом можно реализовать свою фабрику IJob

```
var _scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
_scheduler.JobFactory = new SchedulerServiceJobFactory(_kernel);
```

`SchedulerServiceJobFactory` - это реализация интерфейса `IJobFactory`, а уже в ней можно подписаться, отписаться и вообще все что угодно сделать, т.к. инстанцирование объекта `IJob` производится там...